# Array sequenciado dentro de dropdown

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, array

Gente, eu tenho um código que printa os arrays se eu definir os valores, mas gostaria que essa sequência fosse automática. Deixa eu mostrar pra ficar mais claro.

```
<?php

  $busca_produtos = new Produto;
  $produto = $busca_produtos->busca_todos_produtos();

  $busca_desc = new Produto;
  $desc_produto = $busca_produtos->busca_desc();

 ?>
```

Nesse código acima ele puxa os valores dos arrays certinhos; abaixo, eu printo os valores:

```
 <datalist class="" id="browsers" >
    <option value="<?php echo $produto[0]['cod_produto']; ?>"><?php echo $desc_produto[0]['desc_produto'] ;?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $produto[1]['cod_produto']; ?>"><?php echo $desc_produto[1]['desc_produto'] ;?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $produto[2]['cod_produto']; ?>"><?php echo $desc_produto[2]['desc_produto'] ;?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $produto[3]['cod_produto']; ?>"><?php echo $desc_produto[3]['desc_produto'] ;?></option>   
 </datalist>
```

Como vocês podem ver, eu tive que dar valor ao array. O problema é que se eu colocar, exemplo, $produto[5345]['cod_produto'], obviamente vai aparecer um erro, porque a linha 5345 não existe no banco.

Minha pergunta é: existe alguma forma de eu puxar TODOS os valores do banco e printar ali nos options separadamente sem precisar especificar a linha em que ele se encontra? Como se cada valor de array fosse uma opção do datalist?

Comment: Faz um `SELECT` de todos os valores no DB  e usa um `foreach` para iterar sobre todos os resultados dando print neles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando um `foreach` e um contador `$i`

```
<datalist class="" id="browsers" >
    <?php 
       $i = 0;   // declaração do contador
       foreach($produto as $p){
    ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $p['cod_produto']; ?>"><?php echo $desc_produto[$i]['desc_produto'] ;?></option>
    <?php
          $i++; // incremento do contador
       }        // fim do foreach
    ?>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Seria mais fácil usar um `for` normal se é pra manter um `$i` incremental.
Ou usar um `foreach` com `array_map` para juntar os dois arrays.
Ex.: `foreach(array_map(null, $produto, $desc_produto) as $p) {...}`

Comment: Usei o seu código! Muito obrigada, moço.

Answer (score 4):

Tente algo +/- assim

```
<datalist class="" id="browsers" >
  <?php 
  $x = 0; 

  // No lugar de 10 coloca o tamanho máximo retornado na sua busca
  while ($x <= 10) {
    echo "<option value=" . $produto[$x]['cod_produto'] . $desc_produto[$x]['desc_produto'] . "</option>";
    $x++;
  };
  ?> 
</datalist>
```

Comment: Se não houver retorno do banco de dados teu código vai dar erro.
É só usar `while` ao invés de `do..while`.

Comment: Verdade, não me atentei a isso, já corrigi obrigado!

Comment: Obrigada!!! Deu certinho!

Comment: @SílviaDemarchi De nada, só não esqueça de marcar minha resposta como aceita, caso tenha sido ela que você usou!

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso eu prefiro usar o `for`:

```
<datalist class="" id="browsers" >

<?php 
for($i = 0; $i < count($produto); $i++):
?>

<option value="<?php echo $produto[$i]['cod_produto']; ?>"><?php echo $desc_produto[$i]['desc_produto'] ;?></option>

<?php 
endfor;
?>

 </datalist>
```

Mas todas as respostas estão corretas.

A linha comentada abaixo é desnecessária no seu código.

```
  $busca_produtos = new Produto;
  $produto = $busca_produtos->busca_todos_produtos();

  // $busca_desc = new Produto; // <-- esta linha não é necessária
  $desc_produto = $busca_produtos->busca_desc();
```

Comment: Nesses casos eu gosto de usar a [sintaxe alternativa das estruturas](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Como o `for: ... endfor;`. Acho ilegível um `}` perdido no meio do código.

Comment: @fernandosavio sim! Códigos "macarrônicos" já não são muito amigáveis né... Ainda mais usando `}`

Comment: É verdade, muito obrigada por avisar!

Comment: @SílviaDemarchi sem problema.